# Cannot find module 'tailwindcss' heroku error

Tags: reactjs, heroku, tailwind-css

I have this error in Heroku when I deploy the application, this is my `package.json` I have been reading and I still cannot find the solution to this error I have tried instead of putting it in dependencies in dependencies and it does not work.

[image]

[image]

Error in Heroku

[image]

Look at this [UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss' heroku error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693482/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-cannot-find-module-tailwindcss-heroku) and here they do not give any solution to the problem.